# I am new to c++. So please help me in following snippet

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Now when I try to compile `main.cpp`, I get an error as `Undefined symbol  add(int) in module main.cpp` Please help me!

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream.h> 
#include "addition.h"

int main()
{
add(4);
return (0);
}
```

```
//add.cpp
 #include "addition.h"
 #include<iostream.h>
 void add(int a)
{
cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

```
//addition.h
void add(int a);
```

Comment: That seems rather hard to believe. Can you check again that this really is your code. The error I would expect relates to `cout` which would need to be `std::cout`.

Comment: A few things: you probably want `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`, you don't need to include `iostream` in main.cpp as you aren't using it anywhere in main.cpp, and you'll want to learn to use indentation if that's what your actual code looks like. Also, `cout` and `endl` won't be recognized by including the header alone.

Comment: Make sure you link all your objects together in the linking step.

Comment: Are both main.cpp and add.cpp on the build command line? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that main() uses add(). And add is defined in another compilation unit (add.cpp) which is why you get the error message `Undefined symbol add(int)`.

You need to tell the compiler to compile both pieces of code and `link` them together:

The easy way:

```
g++ main.cpp add.cpp
```

The long way:

```
# 1 Make the main object file
g++ -c main.cpp
# 2 Make the add object file
g++ -c add.cpp

# Link the object files into an executable.
g++ main.o add.o
```

Comment: I am using turbo c++ 3.0 and running it under windows.

Comment: @Stacker: Name of the command changes not the principle. But I am not familiar with this turbo C++ thing so can not help further.

Comment: @Stacker : Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991. C++ was only formally standardized in 1998, and has changed **drastically** in the subsequent years. Do yourself a favor and get an actual, _modern_ C++ compiler.

Comment: @Stacker: How do you execute turbo C++ to get the above message (add this information to your question).

Comment: sir i just type tcc main.cpp in cmd  (tcc--> turbo cpp compiler)

Comment: and all my three files are in same folder...so how do i link them before compiling..?

Comment: @Stacker: Then replace `g++` above with `tcc`. Note: You link after compiling.